# Handling PATCH requests with javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

We are using our implementation of the javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet class as an error page(defined in the web.xml) in our Spring Web application in order to filter error information, sent to users of our API for security reasons.

As of recently we also have to handle PATCH requests to our API. As the HttpServlet was implemented with HTTP version 1.1 in mind, it does not support PATCH request("PATCH" string as a request method name). If we were to add the functionality, we have to override the whole HttpServlet implementation, which also has negative security connotations for us.

Is there an out of the box way to achieve what we are trying or do we have to switch to another implementation(also viable)?

Comment: can you upgrade to a version of HTTP that supports PATCH?  If no, implementing yourself is the only option, even if you use a 3rd party lib.

Comment: If your server does not include PATCH in the Allow or Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers, the client should not send PATCH.

Comment: It does include PATCH and the client should send it.
We are using the default java library for servlets and it is implemented for HTTP 1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try overriding the `HttpServlet.service` method.
For "DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT", and "TRACE" pass the request to the `super` implementation of service.

For "PATCH" call a `doPatch` method that you define in the overriding class.

Implement `doPatch` in the actual class.

More info about message body:
Checkout an HTTP reference to see which methods support a method body and which do not.
There is a nice table on the [HTTP Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Comment: We used something similar. Since handling for all HTTP methods is the same, we only extended the service() method. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I tried doing this but seems that request parameters does not pass through this way...

Comment: It seems that they need to be passed in the URL and not as body parameters ("data" node in jQuery Ajax).

Answer (score 3):

```
public class CustomServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String method = req.getMethod();
        if (!method.equals("PATCH")) {
            super.service(req, resp);
        }

        this.doPatch(req, resp);
    }

    protected void doPatch(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("At patch method");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `return`, all requests will be of type PATCH and the response will be duplicate:

```java
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String method = req.getMethod();
        if (!method.equals("PATCH")) {
            super.service(req, res);
            return; // <----- add this
        } 
        this.doPatch(req, res);
    }
```